# how to speed up flipclock and stop at a certain point?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, flipclock

I'm currently using [Flipclock.js](http://flipclockjs.com/) to start a counter when the user scrolls past a certain point.

I'm looking for a way to speed this up so it rapidly counts to a time (say 5 minutes, within 5 seconds) and then stop. Essentially I need more of an animation effect than an actual counter.

Has anyone had success with this? Is there something else I could be using to achieve this effect with the flipclock look?

This [gif](https://camo.envatousercontent.com/9478f646d8f7053e8de6bfcc092945b57ae3c218/687474703a2f2f7071696e612e6e6c2f666c69702f70726f6d6f74696f6e2f66756e64732e676966) gives a good example of the speed I am looking for - though ideally would be more consistent

Answer (score -1):

Change the interval in the flipclock.js library.

```
    _setInterval: function(callback) {
        var t = this;
        t.interval = 100;// <-- add this
        t.timer = setInterval(function() {          
            t._interval(callback);
        }, this.interval);
    }
```

This addition makes it flip every 100 ms.